# Fatal error: Invalid template

Tags: php

i am new to PHP and it seems i ran into some deathcode.
Error given:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Invalid template: FPage in /home/jharvard/vhosts/localhost/includes/functions.php on line 218
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0001  124636  {main}( )   ../buy.php:0
2   1.3034  144340  render( )   ../buy.php:6
3   1.3035  144476  trigger_error ( )   ../functions.php:218
```

This is as soon as i POST to my form at Buy.php

```
    <?php 
require("../includes/config.php");
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $symbol = $_POST["symbol"];
    $price = lookup($symbol)["price"];
    render("FPage", ["price" => $price]);
}
else{render("BuyPage.php");}

?>
```

BuyPage and FPage are respectively:

```
<form action="buy.php" method='post'><input name="symbol"><input name="SAmount"><input type="submit"></form>
```

and

```
<?php 
    echo $price;
?>
```

And functions.php(If need be) is at http://pastebin.com/Kd9Zg32S

What i was going for:
Pretty much a simple program to "buy" fake stocks for a programming challange. Lookup pretty much looks up a stock's symbol on yahoo finance and returns a list. 
Render pretty much renders the template along with header and footer as well as extracting and inputting any variables passed in. 
However about half way around the place i get struck here with a "hairball" of bugs, and this one i just cant seem to pass by.

Debugging help is highly appreciated.
Ps: Config is just a file that checks if the user is logged in, loading in functions e.t.c e.t.c, i brought in all the code that i thought was needed, if more is needed please notify me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
    render("FPage", ["price" => $price]);
}
else{render("BuyPage.php");}
...
```

You render "FPage" and "BuyPage.php"
"BuyPage.php" works but FPage does not.

Try replacing "FPage" by "FPage.php".

Comment: Thanks, silly me :/. Will mark correct as soon as the default timer is up.